# D3+Leaflet Circle SVG element not displaying any color

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I have to display on a map with d3 some svg circle elements.

This is the code of one of them pointed on Rome with some style attributes setted with D3.

```
var feature = g.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "#006600")
    .style("fill", "#00cc00")
    .attr("r", 20);
```

As you can see on the image below, the element block is not displayed correctly with the color specified on the right panel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwGLD.png

EDIT: 
ok the whole problem of that is actually on the CSS rules.
Infact setting the width and height property of svg element like this :

```
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg").style("width", "10000").style("height", "10000"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");
```

the circles appear on the map.
 Now this could be a soultion, but would be better with a size fitting the  group element inside (if possible) or at least the window of the browser.
 I did not succeed yet, but i have tried setting width and height properties to 100% (won't work without setting div parent too leading to an unwanted view).

Comment: Looks like it's behind the map. Try reordering the elements.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle. You are not passing cx and cy properties. Are you using other code to set cs and cy attribute?

Comment: See my answer. I hope you are done using my code.

Comment: i was using the trasform attribute to traslate them, with cx and cy is nearly the same ( i tried ths option too). The problem consist all in the css property of the svg container. Its a little tricky to deal with it and found the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got your problem. Before selecting the svg use `map._initPathRoot();`

You have to using like the following way

```
map._initPathRoot();
var svg = d3.select("#map-container").select("svg").append("g");
var feature = svg.append("circle")
.style("stroke", "#006600")
.style("fill", "#00cc00")
.attr("r", 20);
```

Comment: i dont know why the first time (and the many times after) i've tried this solution, didn't work at all. But now,maybe for desolation xD, i have retried on more time and IT WORKED. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing properties inside `style`, try writing it as

```
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" stroke="rgb(0, 102, 0)" stroke-width="3" fill="rgb(0, 204, 0) />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Leaflet, you might want to just add circles using Leaflet's circle maker and then add the appropriate attributes/class. You can then select the class as needed in w/ D3.

```
L.circleMarker([+latitude,+longitude],{
                        color: 'steelblue',
                        fillColor: 'steelblue',
                        fillOpacity: 0.2,
                        radius:10,
                        className: "tweet_location_pre_data"
                    }).addTo(map)
```

You can see my example [here](https://github.com/blehman/maperator/blob/master/js/viz7.js#L288) but just be warned, I didn't clean up this code.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing this solution, but i'm attempting to control the svg element properties with specific dataset record attribute ( e.g. color and radius of the circles with some value inside a Json file).

Comment: Not sure I get ya @claudius_dev. In the link that I posted, I'm iterating through tweets and only add circles when the data contains the property 'tweets_geo_with_media'. In the same way, you could certainly control the color, fill, radius, ect. attribute based on your data values. Happy to help if that doesn't make sense.